# Cucumber - Can you go Then When Then?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Is this formatting okay?

```
 Background:
    Given I am at the homepage
    When I supply my shopify url

 Scenario: New install
    Then I get taken to Oauth page
    When I supply my shopify credentials
    Then I get taken to the app index page
```

I don't want the Oauth page to run before every scenario, only the first two steps.

Comment: Cucumber doesn't care. You can then then then if you like. The purpose for the different ones is to make it more readable, so people know the purpose. Given is to set up the test; When is to trigger the test; Then is verify the result. Your original format works. The questions for me are 1) do you want the test to stop if the oath page doesn't open?, 2) what user would call things oauth page and login credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `Background` like below -

```
 Background:
  Given I am at the homepage
  And I supply my shopify url

Scenario: New install
  Then I get taken to Oauth page
  When I supply my shopify credentials
  Then I get taken to the app index page
```